# Backbone.js sync - PHP return

Tags: php, rest, backbone.js

I'm learning to work with Backbone.js and set up the following environment:

```
/* define the model */
var Login = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:"api/index.php/login/"
});

/* the following code is contained in a view method */

var login = new Login({
    email: $("#email").val(),
    pass: $("#pass").val()
});

var result = Backbone.sync('create',login);
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

In the "index.php" on the server the correct method is called and the data is correctly available.

The alert just outputs: `{"readyState":1}`

Now my question: What should the server (index.php) return/output to answer the client?
I'd like to transfer data back to the client to e.g. display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Backbone.sync()` is an *asynchronuous* operation. You cannot do

```
var result = Backbone.sync('create', login);
```

because `sync()` does not *return* anything useful. It sends the request to the server and returns immediately, long before the server's response has arrived.

Use the [`options` parameter](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync) and place `success` and `error` callback functions there.

```
Backbone.sync('create', login, {
  success: function () {
    // whatever you want to do when login succeeds
  },
  error: function () {
    // display an error message
  }
});
```

The `error` callback would be executed if the server returned an `401 Unauthorized` response, for example; the `success` callback when the server returns `200 OK`.

For documentation on how to use these callbacks and what other options you can use, read the [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) docs.

Comment: works like a charm
thanks for correcting this very basic misunderstanding